# How to display non-SSL images on HTTPS connection?

Tags: ssl, image, https

On my https web site, how can I display images from a web site without a certificate?

I own the example domain of:

- http://**www**.example.com
- http://**static**.example.com (used for my CDN)

I own a certificate for **www**.example.com but not for **static**.example.com.

On my www.example.com domain, you can register for the service over SSL using http**S**://www.example.com

On the registration form (www.), I want to display images from my CDN which is on http://**static**.example.com but don't own a certificate for that subdomain.

On the https://www.example.com registration form - I'm using AJAX to dynamically pull over the image from http://static.example.com. It seems that the web browser does not display non-SSL images at all when using AJAX. However, *if* that image were located on the http**S**://www.example.com domain (the same as the registration form), the image will display via AJAX.

For architecture & design reasons, I would like to keep those images on my CDN (static.example.com) without having to purchase a certificate.

Does anyone know how I can display these images via AJAX from my non-SSL subdomain on my http**S**://www.example domain?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 19):

you can make your own ssl proxy.

Run all the images through this script.
Just make a file and put this PHP code inside. Use `curl` or `file_get_contents` to echo out the content.

So if you want to call the secure image, you call it like this:

`https://mysecureserver.com/path_to_this_script/?url=[base64 encoded image link]`

```php
<?php   
  $strFile = base64_decode(@$_GET['url']);
  $strFileExt = end(explode('.' , $strFile));
  if($strFileExt == 'jpg' or $strFileExt == 'jpeg'){
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
  }elseif($strFileExt == 'png'){
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
  }elseif($strFileExt == 'gif'){
    header('Content-Type: image/gif');
  }else{
    die('not supported');
  }
  if($strFile != ''){
    $cache_ends = 60*60*24*365;
    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Cache-Control: maxage=". $cache_ends);
    header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time() + $cache_ends).' GMT');

    //... [and get the content using curl or file_get_contents and echo it out ]

  }
  exit;
?>
```

Comment: One thing to add ... My server config blocks out requests containing '==' (as they are often used in malicious scan activity). `base64_encode` strings often end with '=='. This can be corrected by using `urlencode(base64_encode($url))`  on creation, and then `base64_decode(urldecode(@$_GET['url']))` in the code above.

Comment: This is good, but be careful of security issues here. make sure to ONLY allow certain urls of domains to be fetched... aka whitelisted domain.

Comment: Sorry, but I'd say that this is bad quality code. The general approach works and makes sense, _but_: deriving the mimetype from the requested url is horrible! It should be derived from the actual image loaded. And even more robust would be to use those headers (incuding the content type header) sent by the backend server. That should know best what headers are suitable.

Comment: Note that this will defeat the point of having a CDN at all, coz the job of CDN is to server content from different servers, but this solution will put it through your server anyway. So your server will server the image to the CDN, then fetch it back from the CDN. So if you do this then just stop the CDN and serve the static content from your server, then no PHP overhead.

Comment: Use CURL if php_openssl is not available or off and/or allow_url_fopen is not on, also implement cases where there is no extension in URL or there is  something after extension in URL...

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to do this without a certificate for static.example.com that will not trigger a security warning or prompt in some browsers (particularly Internet Explorer).

GoDaddy sells SSL certificates for $30ish. I'd say spring for the little bit of cash.

Answer (score 2):

Just like you would include an https image:

```
<img src="http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif" />
```

Some browsers might complain to the user, though, that you're loading insecure resources for a secure page. Nothing you can do about that.

Comment: When using AJAX, browser don't get the opportunity to complain since the image is being dynamically loaded ... instead, the browser simply doesn't display the image.  Which is the entire question, any way around this behavior?

Comment: "Which is the entire question", heh... It wasn't until you completely changed it.

Comment: But this isn't safe. The whole reason people use ssl is privacy, what's the point of sending http images?

Answer (score 2):

You must serve all content that you link to or embed (directly or via AJAX) on a page served over HTTPS by using `https://` references.

One way of going around the 3rd-party, plain-HTTP content problem is to serve that content via a reverse proxy that uses HTTPS, possibly on your site or a service for this. There might be legal implication in doing so, depending on whether it's considered as mere proxying or duplicating content (perhaps similarly to what Google cache does). In addition, by doing so, you're effectively vouching for the content you embed this way.

Answer (score 2):

There is a fantastic solution you are looking for.
https://images.weserv.nl/docs/

src="//images.weserv.nl?url='Your image url here'"

For example

```
 <img src="//images.weserv.nl?url=http://expertweblancer.com/assets/img/illustration/6.png">
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a really old question but thought I'd throw in my $.02 anyway.

I am assuming the subdomain of http://static.example.com is also a subdirectory/folder of http://www.example.com (I.E. http://www.example.com/static) as is the case with most hosting these days.

You can varify this but browsing to http://www.example.com/static and https://www.example.com/static … do you see the same page as you would if you browse to http://static.example.com

If that is true you can feed the image like this …

https://www.example.com/static/image.ext

One other possibility for those on typical shred hosting is using the shared cert many hosting provider provide. Check with the hosting companies support. They are usually something like this …

https://host.hostcoserver.com/~user/dir/image.ext

Hope you all find this useful!

Comment: It would have been better to post the answer here, rather than direct visitors to a blog post, especially for a very old question.

Comment: I edited the question to use the answer given by the user at the blog post and removed the external link.

Answer (score 0):

To extend [@Jaka Jančar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/765779/how-to-display-non-ssl-images-on-https-connection/765784#765784), do you NEED to download the images via AJAX?
You can replace the AJAX call with this: add an IMG element dynamically.

```
function load_image_instead_of_ajax_call(dom_parent_element,image_url) {
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.onload = your_success_callback_function;
    img.onerror = your_error_callback_function;
    img.src = image_url;
    dom_parent_element.appendChild(img);
}
```

This way, your image resource gets loaded, with a proper callback on success/error.

Some browsers may complain that your page contains both http and https content, but it is not very common (this seems to be off by default in most browsers).

Answer (score -1):

I hit this problem for a local news aggregator that I run, I ended up using PHP's copy to pull the images over to my server and then serving them up SSL.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php