# How to link from SSL to external imgages with reverse proxy script

Tags: php, ssl, proxy, external, reverse

Would really appreciate some guidance to as why I cant get this reverse proxy script to work.

**Context**

- I am building a privacy search engine at https://motherpipe.co.uk
- The site is on https and I want to protect the users from other sites knowing what they search for, who they are and so on.
- I am integrating twitter search api results in our search results pages. We want to include the twitter profile thumbnail image on our search result page.
- Because we are protecting our users, we can not link directly from the results page to the images on the twitter server.
- Therefore I am using a PHP script to fetch and return the file to the page, so to not expose the client IP to the Twitter servers.
- I am using a script by [alireza-balouch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1107824/alireza-balouch) I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/765779/how-to-display-non-ssl-images-on-https-connection).

**The problem**

- I can not seem to link to this script properly from my results page. When I run it, the result page is calling the script (I think) but the result is that the HTML still contains the direct link to the Twitter server. I would expect all these links to point to my script on the server instead.
- Also - if I try the script directly in a browser, I simply get nothing from an input of for example "reverseproxy.php?url=aHR0cDovL3d3dy5wYWdpbmFzcHJvZGlneS5jb20ubXgvcGVtcG8yL0RWRF9kaXNjby5qcGc="

**Question:**

How can I tweak this so that the images show up, but the image links in the HTML page all point to my own server rather than Twitter's?

Any feedback or ideas would be much appreciated.

The code on the results page:

```
$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json';
$requestMethod = 'GET';
$getfield = '?q=sweden&result_type=recent';
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);


$response = $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
         ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
         ->performRequest();

$obj = json_decode($response, true);  
$reverseproxy = "https://mysercureserver/reverseproxy.php?url=";   

echo "<div><ul>";
foreach ($obj["statuses"] as $index => $result) {

$tweet = $result['text'];
$tweet = ereg_replace("[[:alpha:]]+://[^<>[:space:]]+[[:alnum:]/]","<a href=\"\\0\">\\0</a>", $tweet);
$user = $result['user']['screen_name'];
$profile_image = $result['user']['profile_image_url'];
$profile_image = base64_encode($profile_image);
$image = file_get_contents("https://mysecureserver/reverseproxy.php?url=".$profile_image);
echo "<li>";
echo "<img src=\"".$image."\" width=\"25px\" height=\"25px\" />";
echo "<a href=\"http://twitter.com/$user\">@$user</a>";
echo " $tweet";
echo "</li>";
} 

echo "</ul></div>";
```

and the script:

```
$file = base64_decode(@$_GET['url']);
$aFile = end(explode('.' , $file));
    if($aFile == 'jpg' or $aFile == 'jpeg'){
        header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    }elseif($aFile == 'png'){
        header('Content-Type: image/png');
    }elseif($aFile == 'gif'){
        header('Content-Type: image/gif');
    }else{
        die('not supported');
    }
    if($file != ''){
        $cache_expire = 60*60*24*365;
        header("Pragma: public");
        header("Cache-Control: maxage=". $cache_expire);
        header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time() + $cache_expire).' GMT');

echo $file;

    }
    exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

So I tweaked the script myself and got it to work using curl. Working script:

```
$file = base64_decode(@$_GET['url']);
    $aFile = end(explode('.' , $file));
    if($aFile == 'jpg' or $aFile == 'jpeg'){
        header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    }elseif($aFile == 'png'){
        header('Content-Type: image/png');
    }elseif($aFile == 'gif'){
        header('Content-Type: image/gif');
    }else{
        die('not supported');
    }
    if($file != ''){
        $cache_expire = 60*60*24*365;
        header("Pragma: public");
        header("Cache-Control: maxage=". $cache_expire);
        header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time() + $cache_expire).' GMT');


//The cURL stuff...
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "$file");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
$picture = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
//Display the image in the browser
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
echo $picture;

    }
    exit;
```