# trouble of show http image in https

Tags: php, image, http, https

I need to embed http image in my https website, because if simply use `<img src="http://www.sof.com/abc.jpg"/>` will not show in https website.

After that, I was search some topic of this function, I found that something like `<img src="https://www.some.com/image.php?url=http://www.sof.com/abc.jpg" />` can be show in https

So now I was genarate 2 source. 1 is the image file: `http://www.website1.com/abc.png`,

and the https web adress is `https://fb.ccc.com`

after that I create the image.php code was below:

```
<?  
        $strFile = base64_decode(@$_GET['url']);
        $strFileExt = end(explode('.' , $strFile));
        if($strFileExt == 'jpg' or $strFileExt == 'jpeg'){
            header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
        }elseif($strFileExt == 'png'){
            header('Content-Type: image/png');
        }elseif($strFileExt == 'gif'){
            header('Content-Type: image/gif');
        }else{
            die('not supported');
        }
        if($strFile != ''){
            $cache_expire = 60*60*24*365;
            header("Pragma: public");
            header("Cache-Control: maxage=". $cache_expire);
            header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time() + $cache_expire).' GMT');



        }
        exit;
?>
```

if I request the link: https://fb.ccc.com/image.php?url=http://www.website1.com/abc.png , then the page will be respone `not supported`

I was also try `$strFile = $_GET['url'];` but it only show blank.
if I try `$strFile = var_dump(@$_GET['url']);` and the page will respone `string(31) "http://www.website1.com/abc.png" not supported`

so someone can help to find out what is my script problem?

thank you very much!

Comment: Apart from the direct question there are a few issues with this approach: you create an open proxy here, allowing everyone to miss use your script to fetch arbitrary files, at least images on your behalf. You certainly could try to limit access to that, but the overall approach is questionable. Just imagine someone retrieving child pornographic images by that means, your systems IP address would be registered and you will ahve to expect some questions afterwards...

Comment: if use `$strFile = var_dump(@$_GET['url']);` the page just show `string(31) "http://www.website1.com/abc.png" not supported` only.

Comment: Not sure if this is your issue at hand, _but_: the way you dump the url as shown towards the end of your question does not make sense: `$strFile = var_dump(@$_GET['url']);`, since `var_dump()` will return void, so nothing. After that your conditionals _have to_ result into the else case and the error message you output, since you assign nothing as value to `$strFile`.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/765779/how-to-display-non-ssl-images-on-https-connection) actually the code above I was find out on this topic, but I cannot comment if my reputation below 50.. the `var_dump` just my imagine.. I am newbie..

Comment: That code is not exactly good code, there are some further issues with that approach. In general the approach works, _but_: the actual code that retrieves the image from the URL is _not_ part of that code. The link you posted shows a comment towards the bottom, where the code is missing. I hope you understood that. Then the mime type sent as header is derived from the url posted as an argument which does not make much sense. It should depend on the actual image retrieved instead. So I am not sure if that advice you found is such a good source...

Comment: so how to improve the script? can you please advice that? thank you.