# HTTPS and Wordpress, not all pages show the lock, some have caution with lock

Tags: wordpress, https, mixed-content

I want every page to be HTTPS, it does go to HTTPS but there is a yield on may pages, due to images probably (i'm guessing).  How do I get all elements to be HTTPS (to get rid of the yield) in my wordpress site.

Comment: You might want to check out this answer: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/765779/how-to-display-non-ssl-images-on-https-connection

Comment: I already have an ssl certificate, i believe just the images are not secure, but it's in wordpress, so i'm not sure how to make them secure.